# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SMAC_optimizer'

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning

I try to run **pySMAC** to find input parameters to a python function minimizing the return value. 
I followed the example from [Quickstart Guide](http://pysmac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html), but it raises the exception:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SMAC_optimizer'`

Import section includes: `import pysmac`.

Exception is in line:

`opt = pysmac.SMAC_optimizer()`

Why is it raising this exception and how can I solve it?

I've already asked developers on [github](https://github.com/sfalkner/pySMAC/issues/22), but they haven't give any answer yet. 
Also I've read similar questions on StackOverflow, but there is no solution.

Comment: If you called your file `pysmac.py`, don't call it that.

Comment: It isn't my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned repository https://github.com/automl/pysmac.git and run `python setup.py install`.

It helps, SMAC works after that.

Note:
Installing pysmac via pip using `pip install pysmac` caused the error.

This didn't help either:
`pip install git+https://github.com/automl/pysmac.git`